# Why is numpy list access slower than vanilla python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I was under the impression that numpy would be faster for list operations, but the following example seems to indicate otherwise:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def ver1():
    a = [i for i in range(40)]
    b = [0 for i in range(40)]
    for i in range(1000000):
        for j in range(40):
            b[j]=a[j]

def ver2():
    a = np.array([i for i in range(40)])
    b = np.array([0 for i in range(40)])
    for i in range(1000000):
        for j in range(40):
            b[j]=a[j]

t0 = time.time()
ver1()
t1 = time.time()
ver2()
t2 = time.time()

print(t1-t0)
print(t2-t1)
```

Output is:

```
4.872278928756714
9.120521068572998
```

(I'm running 64-bit Python 3.4.3 in Windows 7, on an i7 920)

I do understand that this isn't the fastest way to copy a list, but I'm trying to find out if I'm using numpy incorrectly.  Or is it the case that numpy is slower for this kind of operation and is only more efficient in more complex operations?

EDIT:

I also tried the following, which just just does a direct copy via b[:] = a, and numpy is still twice as slow:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def ver6():
    a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    b = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(1000000):
        b[:] = a

def ver7():
    a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    b = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
    for i in range(1000000):
        b[:] = a

t0 = time.time()
ver6()
t1 = time.time()
ver7()
t2 = time.time()

print(t1-t0)
print(t2-t1)
```

Output is:

```
0.36202096939086914
0.6750380992889404
```

Comment: NumPy newbie rule of thumb: If your code has the word `for` in it, you're not getting the benefits of NumPy there.

Comment: Constructing the numpy arrays takes some time. After they're constructed, however, further operations are much quicker than using a vanilla Python list. Since you are constructing two new numpy arrays in every loop iteration, it only makes sense that it would be much slower than using Python lists.

Comment: @pzp No, the numpy arrays are only created once.

Comment: @pzp and for thinking exactly that reason, I changed the code to construct the arrays outside of the functions, reduced it to a single function and timed it without that factor. Still the same.

Comment: @roganjosh Are you sure? I just timed it myself without including the array construction and with user2357112's proper use of numpy, and numpy *killed* vanilla--it was not even close. Also, this is a terribly constructed test... the results are being cached.

Comment: @pzp with the way this way constructed in the question, yes. Setting it up under the instruction the answer of user2357112, numpy wins for me.

Answer (score 6):

You're using NumPy wrong. NumPy's efficiency relies on doing as much work as possible in C-level loops instead of interpreted code. When you do

```
for j in range(40):
    b[j]=a[j]
```

That's an interpreted loop, with all the intrinsic interpreter overhead and more, because NumPy's indexing logic is way more complex than list indexing, and NumPy needs to create a new element wrapper object on every element retrieval. You're not getting any of the benefits of NumPy when you write code like this.

You need to write the code in such a way that the work happens in C:

```
b[:] = a
```

This would also improve the efficiency of the list operation, but it's much more important for NumPy.

Comment: Another note to improve efficiency (not sure whether I should post this under the question instead): Initialize the arrays with generator comprehensions rather than list comprehensions.

Comment: @L3viathan: That wouldn't help; in fact, it'd be outright wrong. Really, the arrays should be `np.arange(40)` and `numpy.zeros([40])`.

Comment: Hi, I tried it with b[:] = a, the vanilla python is still more than twice as fast as numpy.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: That's from a combination of 3 factors: the inputs are fairly small, very little allocation is involved, and the Python list gets to push the work into C too. If you try it with larger arrays, or if you try a mathematical operation (say, elementwise addition), the NumPy array will be way faster.

Comment: @user2357112 OK, thanks. For my application I need arrays of size 40, so I suppose I should stick to Python lists?  Unless there is another advantage of numpy?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: Depends on how much math you're doing, and how well you take advantage of NumPy's features when you're doing that math. Even for arrays of this size, NumPy is way faster than Python built-in data types for math.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Have you removed the inner loop? on my system, doing the `b[:] = a` assignment (just once, not 40 times) is 10x faster than the vanilla Python.

Comment: Increasing just array length and some crude regression seems to show that numpy would break-even at an array length minimum of >4 million with the existing code. Do you know any good resources that would give a learner some rules of thumb on this kind of thing or benchmarks? As someone completely self-taught, all google searches would seem to point to numpy being better for this kind of thing, to the point that you kinda stop questioning it.

Comment: @roganjosh: By "existing code", do you mean `b[:] = a`, or the original loop? I don't think the loop would ever break even, but [`b[:] = a` breaks even at around 200 elements.](http://ideone.com/6Y8duY) I don't know of any rules of thumb, but benchmarking is easy.

Comment: By existing code, I meant the code OP was using, as he commented earlier saying that that particular modification was still taking twice the time. I will try a fresh benchmark when I get chance. Very grateful for this post and answer because I have definitely fallen into the default-to-numpy mode for this. Thank you.

Comment: @roganjosh: It's worth noting that for actual math, NumPy starts winning at a much lower array length. For example, [`a+b` with arrays beats `[x+y for x, y in zip(a, b)]` for lists at a length of about 10](http://ideone.com/lWKEUy), and [`numpy.log(a)` beats `[math.log(x) for x in a]` at a length of about 7](http://ideone.com/dIDcx6).

Comment: @user2357112 I verify your results using `b[:]=a`. Using this method, it more than breaks-even on a 200 element array on my PC. I have some more learning to do on what's going on under the hood :)

Comment: @Jaime, yes I removed the inner loop.  Both are doing b[:] = a, and the numpy version takes twice as long.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman can you show your code somehow, either in an edit to OP or otherwise? Even if I keep the inner loop, numpy is now faster once I made the change suggested here.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman vanilla: 0.539999961853, numpy: 0.22000002861. vanilla: 0.55999994278, numpy: 0.22000002861. That's running a copy/paste twice. I can't help from here sorry :(

Comment: @roganjosh what's your OS and python version?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Windows 7, 64 bit. I use Enthought Canopy so that's a bit tougher to answer since I write in Python 2.x, so I assume it defaults to 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you are seeing is Python object creation from C native types.

A Python list is, at it's heart, an array of `PyObject` pointers. When `a` and `b` are both Python lists, doing `b[i] = a[i]` will imply:

- decreasing the reference count of the object pointed by `b[i]`,
- increasing the reference count of the object pointed by `a[i]`, and
- copying the address stored in `a[i]` into `b[i]`.

But if `a` and `b` are NumPy arrays, things are a little more ellaborate, and the same `b[i] = a[i]` then requires:

- creating a Python integer object from the native C integer type stored at `a[i]`, see [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong),
- converting the Python integer object into a native C integer type, and storing its value in `b[i]`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsLong), and
- decreasing the reference count of the temporary Python integer object.

So the difference is mostly in creating and disposing of that intermediate Python object, that lists do not need to do.